# JSON.parse fails in converting it to object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am getting a `ng-class` like this in my dom, how can i access the `twitter` and `yahoo` attributes here.

```
ng-class="{twitter:2 < id , yahoo :2 >id}"
```

`typeof ng-class` is `object`, but when i try to access it like `elem["ng-class"]["twitter"]` does not work.

While doing `JSON.parse(obj)` also fails.

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token t in JSON at position 1

Comment: Well, it's wildly invalid JSON, so it's no great surprise `JSON.parse` won't parse it...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: How can i access the twitter property here?

Comment: There's probably another way to accomplish what you want.  If you explain **why** you want to access `twitter` and `yahoo` in your conditional class, we can probably give you some better options.

Comment: It's not valid JSON, see: http://json.org/

Comment: @cale_b: I want those value for dynamic templating here...

Comment: try ng-class="{twitter:(2 < id) , yahoo :(2 >id)}"

Comment: Do you control what's in that string? That is, can you change it into legal JSON or would that break other things?

Comment: Explain "dynamic templating".  Angular does that beautifully, and I've never had to attempt to access the `ng-class` in my experience.

Comment: What is `2 < id`? Is that supposed to be a string or an actual comparator ?

Comment: @Damon: It's an expression. Angular's `ngClass` directive understands that syntax, and will give the element the class `twitter` if the expression is true and won't if it's false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have there isn't an object, it's a pair of conditionals in an [`ngClass` directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass): The element will have the class `twitter` if `2 < id` is true, and will have the class `yahoo` if `2 > id` is true (it will have neither of them if `id == 2`).

Since it's not an object, there's no property to access.

Comment: typeof ng-class="{twitter:2 < id , yahoo :2 >id}" gives me an object.. is there a way to access the twitter property here.

Comment: @Shane: I have no idea what you mean by `typeof ng-class`. I can't imagine any context in which you could write that and have it be valid code. Perhaps an [mcve] in the question would help.

Comment: typeof "{twitter:2 < id , yahoo :2 >id}" returns me an object instead of string... here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/9wg1trx1/1/

Comment: I am trying to replace this {{ind}} with 0, 1, 2, 3, 4... so on

Comment: @Shane: What you're accessing there is an *attribute* on an element. You can get the text of the attribute via `getAttribute`, e.g. `val.getAttribute("ng-class')`: http://jsfiddle.net/9wg1trx1/2/ You can update the value of the attribute with `setAttribute`, **but** I very much doubt this is the right way to go about what you're doing, unless Angular hasn't yet been run on the elements in question (in which case, it should be fine). If Angular's already been run on the elements in question, it has presumably already tried to use that `ng-class` attribute with the `{{ind}}` in it.

Comment: angular has not run on the elements... i see the {{ind}} is always 1... instead of 0, 1 but anyway thanks a lot...

Answer (score 0):

Please add quotes and `()` for values of object like this:

```
ng-class="{'twitter': (2 < id), 'yahoo': (2 >id)}"
```

With this update you not see `Uncaught SyntaxError` again!

Comment: Code-only answers aren't helpful.  Explain what you did, how / why it solves the problem.

Comment: Moreover, this has nothing to do with the problem or the question. The `()` there are completely unnecessary and change nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Works as expected as you can see in this [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/jbNSqOPfUlsqsvYdDvLN?p=preview)

When interpreted by Angular, ngClass assigns class values to `class` element attribute.

> when i try to access it like `elem["ng-class"]["twitter"]` does not work.

If you want to check if the DOM element has "twitter" class simply do it by querying the DOM.